# how to play online video those are on server

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, ios6, video-streaming

I have videos on my server. I would like to play those video on iPhone and iPad.

Could anyone suggest how to deal with such case?

I know how to play video when the same video is in my project using `MPMoviePlayerController`.

Comment: The same thing you can do is, to pass `NSURL` object with your video_url, that's it :)

Comment: Get the url of your video on server, and set the contentURL to the MPMoviePlayerController.

Comment: @yebw : It won't work that way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use WebView to play video.

In .h file add this code :

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
    @interface VideoViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIWebView *playerView;
```

And in .m file :

```
@synthesize playerView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
         self.playerView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 05, 300, 200)];
        [self.view addSubview:self.playerView];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    playerView.delegate = self;
    playerView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    playerView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    playerView.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

And in playBtn action put this code :

```
NSString *yourVideoLink = your video link;
NSString *yourlinkThumbnail = your video thumbnaillink;
[self playVideo: yourVideoLink withWebView:playerView andThumbnailLink: yourlinkThumbnail];


#pragma mark - Webview Delegates

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    //[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading..."];
}
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    //[SVProgressHUD dismiss];
}
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
   // [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
}

#pragma mark - MoviePlayer Methods
- (void)playVideo:(NSString *)urlString withWebView:(UIWebView*)videoView andThumbnailLink:(NSString*)thumbnailImageLink {
    NSString *embedHTML = @"\
    <html><head>\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    body {\
    background-color: transparent;\
    color: white;\
    }\
    </style>\
    <script>\
    function load(){document.getElementById(\"yt\").play();}\
    </script>\
    </head><body onload=\"load()\"style=\"margin:0\">\
    <video id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" \
    width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\" poster=\"%@\" autoplay controls></video>\
    </body></html>";
    videoView.backgroundColor   =  [UIColor redColor];
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, urlString, videoView.frame.size.width, videoView.frame.size.height,thumbnailImageLink];
    [videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoPlayStarted:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoPlayFinished:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
}

-(void)videoPlayStarted:(NSNotification *)notification{
    //self.isInFullScreenMode = YES;
}

-(void)videoPlayFinished:(NSNotification *)notification{
    // your code here
   // self.isInFullScreenMode = NO;
}
```

Comment: This will help you fetch video from youtube, not suitable for playing a simple mp4 video direct from server, it can easily be done by providing the exact server url of the video to MPMoviePlayerController.. Your answer doesn't match with the question..

Comment: @iphonic i know that it will done easily by using MPMoviePlayerController,but i have used this code in my app to play video and i can do many customization using this code. which is good for some reason so we can use it as option of MPMoviePlayerController.

Comment: but yes @iphonic preferred way is to use MPMoviePlayerController.

Comment: @Dilip : One question, so will it does a job of streaming video also? Because I don't want user to wait until video is downloaded...

Comment: @FahimParkar yes, it will do job of streaming video.and does not download all video.i am doing streaming with this code from my server in my project.

Comment: @Dilip : that would be awesome then :) I will try this tomorrow and get back to you with any queries for sure. Thanks a TON :) :)

Comment: @Dilip : I got error as `use of undeclared identifier SVProgressHUD`

Comment: Ahh , its bcoz i am using SVProgressHud library to display Hud you can remove it.I have forgot to remove it.

Comment: @Dilip : Can u send me required code and framework on parkarfahim22@yahoo.co.in

Comment: @FahimParkar check your mail i have sended you the file.

Comment: @Dilip : Thanks a ton... Will get back to you incase of any queries.

Answer (score 0):

We can play videos by embedding HTML on UIWebView.

**Example**

```
    let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 100
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: webURl)!
    let embedHTML = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">body {background-color: transparent;color: black;}</style><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes\"/></head><body style=\"margin:0\"><div><iframe src=\"\(webURl!)\" width=\"\(width)\" height=\"\(height)\" frameborder=\"0\" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div></body></html>"
    webView.loadHTMLString(embedHTML as String, baseURL:url as URL )
    webView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
```