# Display video inside the Uiwebview not in device full screen

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, ios4

I want to display video inside the UIWebview. When we click on the video it plays in device full screen.

How do we play video inside the UIWebview?
Please note that these video files are hosted on youtube or on our server. they are not bundled along with app

Comment: I am sorry but question is ambiguous. Are you playing the video in UIWebview?

Comment: Check out this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681618/how-to-play-online-video-those-are-on-server/14682189#14682189

Comment: did you try my answer Naveenkumar ?

Comment: iNeal was correct. I created an expanded answer based upon his suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To play video in `UIWebView` use below code....

```
NSString *strVedio = @"<video controls> <source src=\"YourVideo.mp4\"> </video>";
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YourVideo" ofType:@"mp4"];
[Webview loadHTMLString:strVedio baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
```

**UPDATE:**

use this below code to display video in `UIWebView` from video URL...

```
  NSString *embedHTML = @"\
  <html><head>\
  <style type=\"text/css\">\
  body {\
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  }\
  </style>\
  </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
  <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
  width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
  </body></html>";

  NSString *strHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, yourURLString, width,height];//set width and height which you want

  [webView loadHTMLString:strHtml baseURL:nil];
  [self.view addSubview:webView];
```

If you want to display in small screen only and without webview then use bellow code..

```
MPMoviePlayerController *videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
[player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];

player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150);

[self.view addSubview:videoPlayer.view];
```

Comment: @Naveenkumar you can play video in webview with above simple code with your local video file .. hope its helpful to you.. :)

Comment: Please note that these video files are hosted on youtube or on our server. they are not bundled along with app.

Comment: @Naveenkumar you got it or not??

Comment: @Naveenkumar now i search about another code and search this answer same like my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992735/video-playing-automatically-in-uiwebview

Comment: @ParasJoshi Ya using this answer we able to play video.But video play in full screen of device.I want to play video inside in UIWebView frame size.Or only half screen of device.

Comment: @Naveenkumar see i update answer here i not use webview but you video display with define frame try it out...

Comment: Hi..Paras Joshi.... can we restrict the UIwebview with out full screen....  Here.. i do not want full screen.. i want to play with in the webview only.. is it possible with UIWebview ?... i am playing you tube videos.. please guide me @ParasJoshi

Comment: @Babul yes you can do this thing... see this line.. NSString *strHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, yourURLString, width,height];//set width and height which you want and also try to set frame of uiwebview...

Comment: When we click on the WebView it is showing the Big Screen  ... i want to disable this.. 2 mins. i wil put the code and i will come back @ParasJoshi

Comment: Hmm.. i placed this code.. still i is expanding to Big view.... when i click play.. it is showing big screen... i placed your updated code.. @ParasJoshi

Comment: above code is working dude just change the frame of uiwebview and also pass width and height parameter like 200,200 and also set frame like CGRectMake(10,10,200,200);

Comment: please see my code once... am i doing any thing wrong?... http://pastie.org/8482398 @ParasJoshi

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41254/discussion-between-babul-and-paras-joshi)

Comment: I try to play multiple video in multiple webview but only last webview video play.how i can play all webview video.

Comment: Hi @ParasJoshi want to hide the next and previous control button do you have any idea how to do that.

Comment: Hi @Jitendra if you want to hide that button controls of the MPMoviewPlayerControl then you can set that object control style to none i.e. '[movieObject.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];'

Comment: HI @ParasJoshi I am not using MPmoviePlaye. I am using simple webview.

Comment: Okay. So you are playing the video using UIWebView. right?

Comment: Yes. But in fullscreen I want to hide the next and previous control button.

Comment: Ohh.. I'll look into that and will get back to you if there is any solution with this condition. In the meantime, you can search about it with the html5 video player. Maybe you'll find the solution from there.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should try this property of `UIWebView` class.

> [allowsInlineMediaPlayback](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW32)
>
> A Boolean value that determines whether HTML5 videos play inline or
>   use the native full-screen controller.

Comment: Important note from the docs: *"In order for video to play inline, not only does this property need to be set on the view, but the video element in the HTML document must also include the webkit-playsinline attribute."*

Answer (score 4):

I had the same requirement, to play video inline inside a UIWebView. Additionally, I needed the video to play immediately without waiting for the user to press the play button.

To accomplish this I added this property to the UIWebView:

```
webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
```

Then, in combination it is also required to add a "webkit-playsinline" attribute be included within the HTML5 video element on the web page that is providing the video source url.

```
<video src="assets/myMovie.m4v" webkit-playsinline></video>
```

See the apple doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW32

Here is my complete Obj-C example to create a full screen UIWebView. Add this to a viewDidLoad method of a UIViewController:

```
NSURL *websiteUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/myMovie.m4v"];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:websiteUrl];

UIWebView * webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
webView.opaque = NO;
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[webView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
[self.view addSubview:webView];

// Width constraint
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:webView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                     multiplier:1
                                                       constant:0]];

// Height constraint
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:webView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                     multiplier:1
                                                       constant:0]];

// Center horizontally
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:webView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0]];

// Center vertically
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:webView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0]];
```

Comment: does this video stay in uiwebview if you press fullscreen? does not it change to native AVPlayer?