# How to Restrict the Video Playing With in the UIWebView Only as in the given Frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

My requirement is I do not want to show the video playing in full screen.
For that initially, I choose the `MPMoviePlayerController`. By using this static videos i.e, which is in our app are playing well but the YouTube videos i.e., contains URL are not playing, instead of that it shows blank screen.
I tried in these ways:-  http://pastie.org/8484597
 You may think that all the ways are same.. But I tried all the ways as I googled I got these are all the ways.

Later, I moved to `UIWebView`. Yes, it is absolutely good.. it is playing my videos with No Doubt. Here I am extracting the youtube id and playing. But here, I do not want to play the video in full view. But when I want to play the video we have to click on the `UIWebView` then instantly it is showing full screen with video playing. But, I want to play with in the web view only.

I followed this link but same problem.. [Display video inside the Uiwebview not in device full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922017/display-video-inside-the-uiwebview-not-in-device-full-screen)
I tried in these ways.. http://pastie.org/8484621

(I used `LBYouTubeExtractor` also. it plays good but it is not playing all the videos. For some videos it throws `_itemFailedToPlayToEnd` error).

Please guide me how to do in `UIWebView`?.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the video within a html file and remember to add `webkit-playsinline` and change the webview attribute `webview.allowsInlineMediaPlayback =YES;` Then load the html file with the webview. This works for me.

The html file is like

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <video
        webkit-playsinline
        src="prog_index.m3u8"
        height="200" width="200"
        type="video/m3u8"
    >
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Hi Er Li.. i followed as you said .. i placed my code like this http://pastie.org/8488843  i am facing same problem... am i doing any wrong in my code? @Er Li