# Play NSData or byte array form video from iOS and Android in HTML video tag

Tags: android, ios, html5-video, arrays, nsdata

I have video file in encrypted format. Requirement is to decrypt the file in memory and play via HTML video tag. For security purpose, decrypted file should not be stored at physical file and hence decrypted file will be in memory.

Comment: what do you mean by `HTML video tag` ? do you want to play video on `webview` in ios ? or anything else?

Comment: Yes in Web-view. But it will be HTML file loaded in web-view and hence video tag will be used to play video. Is there any other option to play video in webview

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922017/display-video-inside-the-uiwebview-not-in-device-full-screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922017/display-video-inside-the-uiwebview-not-in-device-full-screen)

Comment: Above URL discuss about displaying in full screen or in webview and also it seems that it has some physical file stored as mp4. In my case there will not be physical file and hence need to play byte array or binary form

Comment: from where you got that data ?

Comment: Data is from server which will be stored in encrypted format on device. And decryption should be done in memory and directly send to web video player without storing the decrypted file on device